# Grep: Capture just number

Tags: grep

I am trying to use grep to just capture a number in a string but I am having difficulty.

```
echo "There are <strong>54</strong> cities | grep -o "([0-9]+)"
```

How am I suppose to just have it return "54"? I have tried the above grep command and it doesn't work.

`echo "You have <strong>54</strong>" | grep -o '[0-9]'` seems to sort of work but it prints

```
5
4
```

instead of `54`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "E" option for extended regex support (or use egrep). On my Mac OSX:

```
$ echo "There are <strong>54</strong> cities" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"
54
```

You also need to think if there are going to be more than one occurrence of numbers in the line. What should be the behavior then?

EDIT 1: since you have now specified the requirement to be a number between `<strong>` tags, I would recommend using sed. On my platform, grep does not have the "P" option for perl style regexes. On my other box, the version of `grep` specifies that this is an experimental feature so I would go with `sed` in this case.

```
$  echo "There are <strong>54</strong> 12 cities" | sed  -rn 's/^.*<strong>\s*([0-9]+)\s*<\/strong>.*$/\1/p'
54
```

Here `"r"` is for extended regex.

EDIT 2: If you have the "PCRE" option in your version of grep, you could also utilize the following with positive lookbehinds and lookaheads.

```
$  echo "There are <strong>54 </strong> 12 cities" | grep -o -P "(?<=<strong>)\s*([0-9]+)\s*(?=<\/strong>)"
54
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB7zY4/1)

Comment: Well there is a lot more text on the page and this code will return _all_ the numbers. Is there a way to just retrieve the # that is between the `<strong>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't parse HTML with regex, use a proper parser :

```
$ echo "There are <strong>54</strong> cities " |
    xmllint --html --xpath '//strong/text()' -
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
54
```

Check [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)