# How to grep the number in text file?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

i want to ask a question about 'awk' , example:

```
awk '{print $8}' tes.txt

output : size=21341,
```

but i only want to grep number "21341", can you give me solution about how to grep the number?

Comment: As written this make no sense. Do you want the number after size=?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep: Capture just number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827023/grep-capture-just-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print $8}' tes.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*'
output: 21341
```

`grep -o <regex>` prints only the matched parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line. See more detail.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`:

```
awk '{print $8}' tes.txt|sed 's/.*size=\(.*\),$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the part behind `=`, pipe the output to `cut`:

```
awk '{print $8}' tes.txt | cut -d= -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split ($8, s, "="); print s[2]}' tes.txt
output: 21341
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the function `sub` in `awk` to do that.

```
awk '{sub(/^.*=/,"",$8);print $8}' tes.txt
```

`sub(/^.*=/,"",$8)`: Eliminate the pattern before "=", and you would get the numeric part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a grep solution:

```
grep -oP '(?<=size=)\d+' file
```

At the moment it searches the whole file so if you want to restrict it to one specific line you have to use awk before.